# Enforce Atomic Operations x Locks

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, atomic

I have a database model that works similar to a banking account (one table for operations, a nd a trigger to update the balance). I'm currently using SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

```
TABLE OPERATIONS
----------------
VL_CREDIT decimal(10,2)
VL_DEBIT decimal(10,2)

TABLE BALANCE
-------------
DT_OPERATION datetime
VL_CURRENT decimal(10,2)


PROCEDURE INSERT_OPERATION
--------------------------
GET LAST BALANCE BY DATE
CHECK IF VALUE OF OPERATION > BALANCE
   IF > RETURN ERROR
   ELSE INSERT INTO OPERATION(...,....)
```

The issue I have is the following:

The procedure to insert the operation has to check the balance to see if there's money available before inserting the operation, so the balance never gets negative. If there's no balance, I return some code to tell the user the balance is not enough.

My concern is: If this procedure gets called multiple times in a row, how can I guarantee that it's atomic?

I have some ideas, but as I am not sure which would guarantee it:

- `BEGIN TRANSACTION` on the OPERATION PROCEDURE
- Some sort of lock on selecting the BALANCE table, but it must hold until the end of procedure execution

Can you suggest some approach to guarantee that? Thanks in advance.

### UPDATE

I read on MSDN (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)  that if my procedure has BEGIN/END TRANSACTION, and the SELECT on table BALANCE has WITH(TABLOCKX), it locks the table until the end of the transaction, so if a subsequent call to this procedure is made during the execution of the first, it will wait, and then guarantee that the value is always the last updated. Will it work? And if so, is it the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're amenable to changing your table structures, I'd build it this way:

```
create table Transactions (
    SequenceNo int not null,
    OpeningBalance decimal(38,4) not null,
    Amount decimal(38,4) not null,
    ClosingBalance as CONVERT(decimal(38,4),OpeningBalance + Amount) persisted,
    PrevSequenceNo as CASE WHEN SequenceNo > 1 THEN SequenceNo - 1 END persisted,
    constraint CK_Transaction_Sequence CHECK (SequenceNo > 0),
    constraint PK_Transaction_Sequence PRIMARY KEY (SequenceNo),
    constraint CK_Transaction_NotNegative CHECK (OpeningBalance + Amount >= 0),
    constraint UQ_Transaction_BalanceCheck UNIQUE (SequenceNo, ClosingBalance),
    constraint FK_Transaction_BalanceCheck FOREIGN KEY
                    (PrevSequenceNo, OpeningBalance)
                references Transactions
                    (SequenceNo,ClosingBalance)
    /* Optional - another check that Transaction 1 has 0 amount and
       0 opening balance, if required */
)
```

Where you just apply credits and debits as +ve or -ve values for `Amount`. The above structure is enough to enforce the "not going negative" requirement (via `CK_Transaction_NotNegative`), and it also ensures that you know the current balance (by finding the row with the highest `SequenceNo` and taking the `ClosingBalance` value. Together, `UQ_Transaction_BalanceCheck` and `FK_Transaction_BalanceCheck` (and the computed columns) ensure that the entire sequence of transactions is valid, and `PK_Transaction_Sequence` keeps everything building in order

So, if we populate it with some data:

```
insert into Transactions (SequenceNo,OpeningBalance,Amount) values
(1,0.0,10.0),
(2,10.0,-5.50),
(3,4.50,2.75)
```

And now we can attempt an insert (this could be `INSERT_PROCEDURE` with `@NewAmount` passed as a parameter):

```
declare @NewAmount decimal(38,4)
set @NewAmount = -15.50

;With LastTransaction as (
    select SequenceNo,ClosingBalance,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SequenceNo desc) as rn
    from Transactions
)
insert into Transactions (SequenceNo,OpeningBalance,Amount)
select SequenceNo + 1, ClosingBalance, @NewAmount
from LastTransaction
where rn = 1
```

This insert fails because it would have caused the balance to go negative. But if `@NewAmount` was small enough, it would have succeeded. And if two inserts are attempted at "the same time" then either a) They're just far enough apart in reality that they both succeed, and the balances are all kept correct, or b) One of them will receive a PK violation error.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the structure, I'm only able to create/change procedures at the time, that's why I was looking for some kind of lock. But thanks for the help so far. If you can help me out I would appreciate!

Comment: @Tiziani - I've not got anything bright to suggest at the moment. The problem with storing the balance separately/unchecked is that, sooner or later, despite all your best efforts, it's bound to get out of sync with the transactions.

Comment: I really liked your solution, and I'll make some effort to have the permission to change the model. But the way you made it, it will raise an error when I try to make an insert that turns closingbalance negative, right? I'd like at least to be able to check for it in a procedure, and if it is that case, I would prevent the insert at all, and return an error saying "balance negative". Thanks for the solution though!